# How to fix FirstPersonControls in three.js giving the error targetPosition.setFromSphericalCoords is not a function

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

When I try to use the FirstPersonControls it just gives me this error :

> uncaught TypeError: targetPosition.setFromSphericalCoords is not a
>   function
>       at THREE.FirstPersonControls.update (FirstPersonControls.js:276)
>       at animate (main.js:143)

```
const scene = new THREE.Scene()
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement)

const camera = new  
THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 
1000 )
camera.position.set( 0, 10, 100)
camera.rotation.x = -0.5

const starsGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();

for ( let i = 0; i < 10000; i ++ ) {
const star = new THREE.Vector3()
star.x = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread(2000)
star.y = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread(2000)
star.z = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread(2000)
starsGeometry.vertices.push( star )
}

const starsMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial( { color: 0x888888 } )
const starField = new THREE.Points( starsGeometry, starsMaterial )    
scene.add( starField )

controls = new THREE.FirstPersonControls( camera, renderer.domElement )
controls.lookSpeed = 0.1
controls.movementSpeed = 100

const clock = new THREE.Clock( true )

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate )
    renderer.render( scene, camera  )
    controls.update( clock.getDelta() )

}

animate()
```

All I need is to be able to look around with my mouse, and having the pointer still visible, but I can't figure it out how to make it.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not able to reproduce your issue, see https://jsfiddle.net/x7b14wev/.

Comment: I found the issue now, I was loading the script from my local server when I changed the source it somehow started to work, Thanks !